# How to SUM two columns and display the result in the third column by subtracting their aggregates SQL & C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have three columns in my database table, namely `Debit`, `Credit` and `Balance`. I need to calculate the total balance after summing up Total Debit, and total Credit, and show the result in a textbox that is read only.

The code of query is here

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TableName SUM(Debit) MINUS SUM(Credit) AS TotalBalance
```

Now I have to show Total Balance along with Total Debit And Total Credit. Query runs fine but with no apparent results.

Comment: Are you using an ORM?

Comment: What is the problem in calculating the result directly in the C# code?

Comment: I killed `mysql` re-add it if you want

Comment: @muhammad MSDN has great articles on all this. Also it seems like you aren't even able to put a GUI together?

Comment: is this sql server ? It does not seems like a valid sql server statement to me

Answer (score 0):

The query that you want is presumably:

```
SELECT SUM(Debit) - SUM(Credit) AS TotalBalance
FROM TableName;
```

This returns one row with one value that is the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL server , use the below script.

```
    SELECT SUM(debit) TotalDebit,SUM(credit) TotalCredit
       ,SUM(Debit)-SUM(credit) TotalBalance
     FROM TableName
```